# Why does max(iterable) perform much slower than an equivalent loop?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, python-internals

I noticed a strange performance hit from a minor refactoring that replaced a loop with a call to the builtin `max` inside a recursive function.

Here's the simplest reproduction I could produce:

```
import time

def f1(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    best = 0
    for k in (1, 2):
        current = f1(n-k)*n
        if current > best:
            best = current
    return best

def f2(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return max(f2(n-k)*n for k in (1, 2))


t = time.perf_counter()
result1 = f1(30)
print('loop:', time.perf_counter() - t) # 0.45 sec

t = time.perf_counter()
result2 = f2(30)
print('max:', time.perf_counter() - t) # 1.02 sec

assert result1 == result2
```

Both `f1` and `f2` calculate factorial using the standard recursion but with an unnecessary maximization added in (just so I get to use `max` in a recursion while still keeping the recursion simple):

```
# pseudocode
factorial(0) = 1
factorial(1) = 1
factorial(n) = max(factorial(n-1)*n, factorial(n-2)*n)
```

It's implemented without memoization, so there's an exponential number of calls.

The implementation with `max(iterable)` is more than twice slower than the one with the loop.

<strike>Oddly, a direct comparison of `max` vs loop did not demonstrate the effect</strike> (edit: never mind, see @TimPeters answer). Also, if I use `max(a, b)` instead of `max(iterable)` the performance mismatch disappears.

Comment: This performance gap has to do with the generator expression that you passed into `max`: `max(f2(n-k)*n for k in (1, 2)`. Generators do well when it comes to space optimizations and poorly in terms of speed. Generators need to pause and continue until they're fully exhausted. This pause/resume is a big performance hit.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye The problem is that, this could be different form machine to machine. Generally speaking, generators tend to be slow, they have to pause and then resume their jobs.

Comment: @direprobs Either way, the `max` version is still lower even without the gen. exp.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Interesting. I didn't test that yet, I conducted some testing with generators compared with `for` loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really unfair for the `max` function due to the generator expression you're feeding it.

For every invocation of `f2` a new closure needs to be created for `n`, a new function needs to be made (that's the way generator expressions, and list expressions since Python 3 I believe, are implemented; see ['The Details' of PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#the-details)) that wraps up the code object representing the gen-exp. Then this function, which iteratively calls other functions, again gets called.

A tiny snippet of the byte-code in question:

```
14 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (n)
16 BUILD_TUPLE              1
18 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x7f1b667e1f60, file "", line 16>)
20 LOAD_CONST               3 ('f2.<locals>.<genexpr>')
22 MAKE_FUNCTION            8
24 LOAD_CONST               5 ((1, 2))
26 GET_ITER
28 CALL_FUNCTION            1
```

You, of course, don't see any instructions like these in `f1`'s case since it is just doing calls.

When you then call your `max` function, `f2`, a *significant* number of times, as you're doing when recursively calculating the factorial of `30`, the overhead just *piles up*.

A list comprehension version of the function thing pretty much suffers from the same issue. It is a bit faster because list comprehensions are faster than generator expressions.

> If I use `max(a, b)` instead of `max(iterable)` the performance mismatch disappears.

Exactly, no functions are created for every call in this case so you're not seeing that overhead pile up. You're simply providing the arguments here.

Comment: This makes sense; I knew gen exp are not free, I just didn't expect the cost to be material (I saw ~20% runtime increase for the recursive function when using `max(iterable)` in a real program -- not in this toy example). I wonder if there's any way to implement generator expression-like construct without this overhead (perhaps at the cost of some other shortcomings)?

Answer (score 7):

Posting this as "an answer" because useful formatting is impossible in comments:

```
$ python -m timeit "max(1, 2)"  # straight
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.148 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "max([i for i in (1, 2)])" # list comp
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.328 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit "max(i for i in (1, 2))" # genexp
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.402 usec per loop
```

Which shows that the recursion is a red herring.  It's generally true, as these results show, that a genexp is slower than a listcomp, which is in turn slower than using neither.  Since your code is doing more than *just* a max, the timing differences aren't as extreme - but since it's doing *little* more than just a max, the speed of the max part is nevertheless highly significant.

Comment: I used list comps and sorted with `list.sort` and then indexed the max number `L[-1]`, I got very slight improvement in timing. Although, this adds the overhead of sorting the lists each time the condition `n <= 1` is false, I was able to get a (very) slight improvement compared to generator expression with `max`.

Comment: @TimPeters Ahh the reason I didn't see this (so ended up using recursive reproduction) is that my loop was poorly implemented - I used `float` numbers which are 3x slower than `int`. `python -m timeit "best=-float('inf')" "for i in (1, 2):" "  if i > best:" "    best=i"` shows almost the same timing as your `genexp` version, but of course setting `best` to the first element (thus keeping it as `int`) makes it super fast (just like your `straight` version).